# Proper way to pre-fill a sender's signature in bulk?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I currently have a working DocuSign integration going using embedded signing. An administrator logs in, provides consent once (auth code grant, extended scope) and the app can generate sign requests in their name to different users without them needing their own DocuSign accounts.

What I'm trying to build now though is for the administrator to sign as well, and preferably only once for the same document which is then sent to different users. So I'd like to make an embedded signing view for the admin to sign once, then use this same half-signed document/template to create multiple embedded signing views for different users. My client would like the DocuSign audit trail to show that the administrator signed each document, so just pre-filling it with an image won't do.

I've been looking at templates, but haven't been able to find examples of or methods for including a sender signature in a template, or embedded template editing. I'm using the eSign package for C# by the way.

So my question is, is this even possible, and if so what's the proper way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

**If the administrator only needs to sign once** and the signed document is then part of many different envelopes/templates, then I would do this:

1. Have a special/first envelope that the administrator signs with the documents that go in every future signing event.
2. Have administrator sign and complete envelope.
3. Download envelope with the signed document with administrator signature.
4. Use the document from #3 to create templates or new envelopes that then get sent to the different recipients to signature.

**This is not the best way to do it**, because you are in a way bypassing the signature process. The signer sees the signature of the admin as if they signed the same envelope, but in fact, they didn't.

However, this way solves your problem if you don't want the administrator to have to sign more than once.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, if you look at the audit trail it won't show the other signature, correct? Since it's just there visually. The client we're developing this for wants to bulk sign with a "real" DocuSign signature which will fully show in the logs.

Comment: Then you have to do it manually. Meaning, every envelope has to first be signed by admin. Can't re-use their signatures.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not support signature delegation to a software application. So you can't delegate your signature authority to software to sign on your behalf.

In addition to Inbar's answer, your attorney could:

- update the language of the contract to not require your company's employee to sign the contract
- have the contract refer to a letter signed (via DocuSign) that states that the company is in agreement with the contract. Then include the signed letter and its certificate of completion with the original contract